# Is it possible to run code when app terminated?

Tags: flutter

I want to know that is it possible to run code when app terminated?

And how Can I do that if it is possible to do?

Comment: Once when it is terminated or to keep code running permanently after the app was terminated? Please elaborate more on what you try to accomplish.

Comment: If you mean running in foreground, it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) allows you to react to lifecycle events like `suspending`.
There is not really a terminated state, especially on iOS.

If you want to run code while the app isn't running in foreground, you can follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background_fetch`, check this article

https://khore-sid2.medium.com/run-flutter-app-in-background-terminated-state-82f70a0eb999

and `work manager`(ios part could be complicated) plugin